# Two Sum on LeetCode

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a **LeetCode Two Sum** question:

> Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they add up to
> a specific target number.
>
> The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that
> they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2.
> Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are
> not zero-based.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.
>
> Input: numbers={2, 7, 11, 15}, target=9 Output: index1=1, index2=2

The first try was using two for loops, which gave me O(n^2), and unfortunately it didn't pass. Hence I tried to use:

```
target - current = index
```

And search for if the index does exists on a dictionary.

This is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        dic = {}
        
        #A number can appear twice inside the same index, so I use a list
        for i in xrange(0, len(nums)):
            try:
                dic[nums[i]].append(i)
            except:
                dic[nums[i]] = []
                dic[nums[i]].append(i)
          
        try:
            for items_1 in dic[nums[i]]:
                for items_2 in dic[target-nums[i]]:
                    if(items_1+1 != items_2+1):
                        l = []
                        if(items_2+1 > items_1+1):
                            l.append(items_1+1)
                            l.append(items_2+1)
                        else:
                            l.append(items_2+1)
                            l.append(items_1+1)
                        return l
        except:
            pass
```

I developed this locally, and I was able get the correct result with one of the test case that LeetCode was complaining: `[-3,4,3,90], 0`

The output I got was `[1, 3]`, but on LeetCode it returned null, does anybody know why this would happen?

Comment: Does it really matter if a number appears twice in the nums list? All that matters is that you get *a* index, correct?

Comment: Well... If the number was [0, 3, 4, 0], the correct value should be 1st, and 4th index. However, since 0 index is already at the 1st index, what happens is that the 4th index isn't in the dictionary.

Comment: Would you like me to show you how I would write it?

Comment: why did you make a class?  the class contains nothing but a single method.  why not delete the class definition line and leave the method as a stand-alone function?

Comment: The class is required to submit the answer, in my local development, I don't have the class included.

Comment: @Shashank It would be nice, but I'm interested in why would this code not work? Is this because the python version they are using is different than 2.7?

Comment: @user1157751 What version of Python are they using? Note that Python 3.x doesn't have xrange, and *several* other differences exist between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @Shashank I'm using 2.7

Comment: @user1157751 Yes but what version are they using? I'm unfamiliar with LeetCode.

Comment: You're using `nums[i]` in the `try` part as if `i` was still meaningful there...

Comment: Your code will return None in most cases.  In the first line of the try block you are looping through dic[nums[i]].  But i has the value left over from the last iteration of the first for loop.  That's not what you want.  If an exception is raised in the next line (target-nums[i] isn't in the dictionary) you catch it and just suppress it, which causes your method to return None.

Comment: @user1157751 Why are you using one-based indexing and not the default which is zero-based indexing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
def twosum(nums=(6, 7, 11, 15, 3, 6, 5, 3), target=6):
    lookup = dict(((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(nums)))
    return next(( (i+1, lookup.get(target-v)+1) 
            for i, v in enumerate(nums) 
                if lookup.get(target-v, i) != i), None)
```

I have not tested this extensively but the basic logic should be sound. This algorithm can be broken up into two stages:

1. Create a dictionary of value->index for all index, value pairs in nums. Note that you can have multiple values with different indices. In this case, the highest index will be stored in the dictionary and lower indexes will be overwritten. This behavior can be modified, of course, but I don't believe it needs to be for this problem because part of the problem statement is this: "You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution." Thus, each input has a single unique output so we never have to worry about returning a "wrong-pair" of indices.
2. Loop through the enumeration of nums, getting `i` as index, and `v` as value. Check if `target-v` is a key in the dictionary we created, and simultaneously assert that the value pointed to by that key is *not* `i`. If this is ever true, return the tuple `i+1, lookup.get(target-v)+1`.

Comment: Gives the same exact answer as my code, but why isn't my code accepted? :(

Comment: @user1157751 Idk unfortunately, does your code have the same underlying logic as mine? Nuances are important, such as the order in which items are processed and so on.

Comment: @user1157751 Btw, I noticed your logic was `target - current = index`, It really should be `target - current = value that has different index than current`. Perhaps, that is causing an issue.

Comment: This example is wrong.  When you run the code and print the returned value from twosum, you get (4,8) but the correct answer is (4,7).

Comment: @PaulCornelius Please notice: "You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution." I explicitly stated that the dictionary updates values to their highest index. That is why my solution gives (4, 8). The example was just to showcase the behavior of the first line. Even if that sentence was *not* in the problem statement, my answer would still be correct, as (4, 8) is a valid pair of indices that point to values that sum up to the target.

Comment: @PaulCornelius One thing I noticed that I had wrong was that my answer did not give the one-indexed index pair. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Shashank You are right I forgot that sentence in the problem statement.

Answer (score 15):

You want something along these lines:

```
#! python3

def two_sum(arr,targ):
    look_for = {}
    for n,x in enumerate(arr,1):
        try:
            return look_for[x], n
        except KeyError:
            look_for.setdefault(targ - x,n)

a = (2,7,1,15)
t = 9
print(two_sum(a,t))  # (1,2)

a = (-3,4,3,90)
t = 0
print(two_sum(a,t))  # (1,3)
```

Here you build the dictionary of values on an as-needed basis.  The dictionary is keyed by the values you are seeking, and for each value you track the index of its first appearance.  As soon as you come to a value that satisfies the problem, you're done.  There is only one for loop.

The only other detail is to add 1 to each index to satisfy the ridiculous requirement that the indices be 1-based.  Like that's going to teach you about Python programming.

Keys are added to the dictionary using the setdefault function, since if the key is already present you want to keep its value (the lowest index).

Comment: a=(2,7,1,15)  and t=9 then output will be (0,1)

Comment: I could not believe that this had escaped everyone's attention for seven years and fifteen upvotes, so I ran the program again just to make sure.  It does indeed print (1, 2), so you must be doing something wrong.  Are you forgetting to add 1 to the index?

Answer (score 13):

I have just passed the following codes. To take advantage the dictionary and the notes that there is one and only one solution. To search the target-num in the saved lookup dictionary when saving the num in the lookup dictionary one by one. This method could save the space and also prevent the index overwriting when there are two same values in the nums.

```
def twosum(self, nums, target):
    lookup = {}
    for cnt, num in enumerate(nums):
        if target - num in lookup:
            return lookup[target-num], cnt
        lookup[num] = cnt
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer uses zero-based indexing since that's the normal way to index, not one-based indexing. It also uses descriptive variable names, and is written for comprehension.

```
from typing import List, Tuple

def twosum_indices_linear(nums: List[int], target: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    numtoindexmap = {}
    for num1_index, num1 in enumerate(nums):
        num2 = target - num1
        try:
            num2_index = numtoindexmap[num2]
        except KeyError:
            numtoindexmap[num1] = num1_index  
            # Note: Use `numtoindexmap.setdefault(num1, num1_index)` instead for lowest num1_index.
        else:
            return tuple(sorted([num1_index, num2_index]))
```

Examples:

```
print(twosum_indices_linear([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
(0, 1)

print(twosum_indices_linear([3, 3], 6))
(0, 1)

print(twosum_indices_linear([6, 7, 11, 15, 3, 6, 5, 3], 6))
(4, 7)
```

Credit: [answer by joeg](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/23004/here-is-a-python-solution-in-o-n-time/20)

Answer (score 3):

Solution in JavaScript using Set

Time and Space Complexity = 0(n)

```js
  function twoSum(nums, target) {
    const mySet = new Set()
  
    for (const element of nums) {
      const potentialMatch = target - element
      
      if (mySet.has(potentialMatch)) {
        return [potentialMatch, element]
      } else {
        mySet.add(element)
      }
    }
    
    return []
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

### One-pass Hash Table

This can be done in one-pass. **How Teo?** Well, while it's iteratting and inserting elements into the hash, it should also look back to check if current element's complement already exists in the hash. If it exists, we have found a solution and return immediately.

#### Complexity:

Time complexity: ***O(n)***. We traverse the list containing ***n*** elements only once. Each look up in the table costs only ***O(1)*** time.

Space complexity: ***O(n)***. The extra space required depends on the number of items stored in the hash table, which stores at most ***n*** elements.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 15]
const target = 9


/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    const map = new Map()
    
    const l = nums.length
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        const complement = target - nums[i]
        if (map.has(complement)) return [map.get(complement), i]
        
        map.set(nums[i], i)
    }
    
    throw new Error('No two sum solution')
}

const [a, b] = twoSum(nums, target)

const addendA = nums[a]
const addendB = nums[b]
console.log({addendA, addendB})
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone still looking for a javascript solution for this question,

```js
/** 
1. Two Sum

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,

return [0, 1].
* */

/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const numsObjs = {}; // create nums obj with value as key and index as value eg: [2,7,11,15] => {2: 0, 7: 1, 11: 2, 15: 3}

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const currentValue = nums[i];

    if (target - currentValue in numsObjs) {
      return [i, numsObjs[target - currentValue]];
    }
    numsObjs[nums[i]] = i;
  }

  return [-1, -1];
}

console.log(twoSum([3,7,3], 6))
```

Comment: But this uses the same element twice. You have multiple references to nums

Answer (score 1):

My one line solution:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        res=[[nums.index(val),nums[ind +1:].index(target-val)+ ind +1] for ind,val in enumerate(nums) if target -val in nums[ind +1:]]
        return res[0]
```

I can explain if it interests someone :)

Comment: You should add your explanation anyway (without waiting to be asked). That will make your answer far better, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: you have to  explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] twoSum1(int[] nums, int target) 
{
    int[] result = new int[2];
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

 
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
        map.put(nums[i],i);
    
    
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        int anotherValue = target-nums[index];
        
        if(map.get(anotherValue)!=null && map.get(anotherValue)!=i)
        {
            result[0] = index;
            result[1] = map.get(target-nums[index]);
            
            System.err.println("result[0]: " + result[0]);
            System.err.println("result[1]: " + result[1]);
            
            return result;
        }
    }        
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        ls = []
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            item = target - nums[i]
            nums[i] = "done"
            if item in nums:
                if i != nums.index(item):
                    ls.append(i)
                    ls.append(nums.index(item))
                    return ls
```

Comment: That fails in case where array is [3,2,4], and target =6. it returns [0,0] but expected [1,2]

Answer (score 0):

```
def twoSum(nums,target):
    k={value:index for index, value in enumerate(nums)} 
    # using dictionary comprehesion to create a dictionary that maps value to index 
    ans=[[j,k[target-x]] for j,x in enumerate(nums) if target-x in k] 
    # use list comprehension to create a set of answers; make sure no key error by using 'if target-x in k'
    ans=[x for x in ans if x[0] != x[1]] 
    # make sure the two indexes are not the same. E.g. twoSum([1,2,0],2) returns [[0,0],[0,1],[1,2],[2,1]]; and [0,0] is a wrong answer  
    return ans[0]
```

This solution is time efficient (faster than 80% of the solutions on leetcode), but takes lots memory.

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
    def two_sum(arr,targ):
        look_for = {}
        for n,x in enumerate(arr,1):
            try:
               return look_for[x], n
            except KeyError:
               look_for.setdefault(targ - x,n)
```

above but it fails timedome due to call to enumerate taking too long for large arrays.  Better to skip the enumerate and just keep a count of index:

```
def findCombo(l,target):
    lookup = {}
    n = 0
    for x in l:
        try:
            return (n,lookup[x])
        except KeyError:            
            lookup.setdefault (target-x,n)
        n = n + 1

    return None
```

Note:Python timedome question uses index starting at 0

Answer (score 0):

```
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
   output = []
   for i in nums:
        for j in nums:
            if i + j == target and nums.index(i) != nums.index(j):
                output.append(nums.index(i))
                output.append(nums.index(j))
                return output

print(twoSum([2,7,11,15],9))
print(twoSum([3,2,4],6))
```

#OUTPUT

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: There is no "above". If you need to refer to a different answer please refer by link, using the "Share" feature. Please explain your code, ideally as standalone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Shashank was right but the results of this answer start from index 1 in the array so leetcode won't accept it. So here is the same solution with a simple change to start the array from index 0.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self,nums, target):
        lookup = dict(((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(nums)))
        return next(( (i, lookup.get(target-v)) 
            for i, v in enumerate(nums) 
                if lookup.get(target-v, i) != i), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is memory efficient a sit uses list pop method, but takes longer time

```
class Solution:   
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        
        while len(nums)>0:
            ind = len(nums)-1
            item = nums.pop()
            if target-item in nums:
                return [ind, nums.index(target-item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:

```
    d = dict()
    
    for i in range(0, len(nums), 1):
        
        if (d.get(target-nums[i]) != None):
            return [i, d.get(target-nums[i])]
        
        d[nums[i]] = i
```

I too struggled with multiple loops initially, finally slimming down to this.

Answer (score 0):

#this is two pointer approch to solving this problem considering that the given arry is not sorted

```
def twoSum( nums, target):
    nums2 = sorted(nums)
    left = 0
    right = len(nums)-1
    while left <right:
        if nums2[left]+nums2[right] == target:
            x =nums.index(nums2[left])
            nums[x]=None
            
            y=nums.index(nums2[right])
            return [x,y]
        elif nums2[left]+nums2[right] < target:
            left+=1
            
            
            
        else:
            
            right -=1
            
           
    return []
print(twoSum([2,7,11,15],9))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question but I have an easy solution with python dictionary with time complexity o(n)

```
def two_sum1(arr,sum):
complement_dict = {}
for i in range(len(arr)):
    complement = sum - arr[i]
    if complement in complement_dict:
        return [complement_dict[complement], i]
    else:
        complement_dict[arr[i]] = i
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in `JavaScript` using nested for loop**

Time Complexity = O(n^2)

Space Complexity = O(n)

---

Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

[image: test-cases]

```
const twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i = 0;  i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if(j === i) continue;
            if((nums[i] + nums[j]) === target) return [i, j];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        r = []

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp = target - nums[i]
            if temp in r:
                return [i,nums.index(temp)]

            r.append(nums[i])
```

Comment: Why should one use that? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Suppose the list has [4,5,6,7] and the target is 11, the loop will check for all the values. Like in this example it starts with 4, so 11-4 = 7 which is present in the list. So the output would be the index of 4 and 7 i.e. [0,3]

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer, not to the comment section

Comment: Sorry Nico, I am new to this. Next time I will add the explanation to the answer. :-)

Comment: It's always good to find new people contributing to SO - don't hesitate to post answers to other questions, and of course post questions on your own!

Answer (score -1):

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9
l = []
x = 1
length = len(nums) - 1
for i in nums:
    l.append(nums.index(i))
    if (target - i) in nums[x:]:
       l.append(length - nums[::-1].index(target - i))
       break
    else:
       l = []
       x = x + 1
print(l)
```

Please check the submission here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeJtMogExbo

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

this is my answer in C++. I hope you can convert this to python

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        unordered_set<int>s;
        vector<int>ans;
    int j =0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    {
        int temp = target -nums[i];
        //int tempInd = i ;
        if(s.find(temp)!=s.end()){
            //cout<<i<<" ";
             ans.push_back(i) ;
            for(int j=0;j<nums.size();j++)
            {
                if(temp == nums[j]){
                    //cout<<j<<endl;
                    ans.push_back(j) ;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        s.insert(nums[i]);

    }
        return ans ;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my answer more fast in **JavaScript**

```
const nums = [2,7,11,15];
const target = 9;
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      for (let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
          if(nums[i]+nums[j] === target){
            console.log(i, j);
          }
      }
    }
};

twoSum(nums, target);
```

Comment: it will take 0(n*n)