# Python: Prevent double for-loop from returning same indexes of list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am currently working on problem 1 in Leetcode, named "Two Sum."

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such
>   that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
>   you may not use the same element twice.
>
> Example: Given `nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9`,
>
> Because `nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9`, return `[0, 1]`.

My current code is:

```
def twosum_indices(nums, target):
    for i in nums:
        for v in nums[i + 1:]:
            if i + v == target:
                return nums.index(i), nums.index(v)
```

In this, nums is a list of integers, and the program must return two different indexes in a list, such that their true values add up to a given target. Although this works fine on most test cases, it fails on a list like [3,3] where both values are the same, and returns the same index twice, like [0,0] instead of returning the actual answer of [0,1]. Why is this happening?

Comment: You are attempting the naive brute force approach, which is O(n**2) and therefore wrong (because it will take too long when they hit you with the real data). The correct answer is O(n). However, your attempt fails to do what you think because i is a number, but you are using it as an index.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I am sorry. I was going to, but by mistake, I clicked enter. It will not let me edit now.

Comment: @KennyOstrom O(n) only if the array is sorted, I think.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nah, use a `dict`, traverse the sequence adding the index to the `dict`, for each element in seq, check if the complement is in the `dict`.

Comment: Again, you are treating the number i as an index, which it is not, so the second loop is wrong. Step through it in a debugger. Also the code you posted would return None if you pass target=6, nums=[3,3]. You never get to the if statement, and simply fall off the end of the function (which means return None, in python)

Comment: Sorry again. My intent was to start iterating at nums[nums.index(i)+1:] instead, but I realize that in [3,3] this means that v will start at the last element and can't iterate further, so is there another way to do this?

Comment: Even when you fix your index, it will be for naught when you call nums.index which always returns the first index. Try this -- for i in range(len(nums): for j in range(i, len(nums): if nums[i] == nums[j]: return i,j  (Also this works on small inputs, but is too slow ... they eventually want you to come up with a way to make two passes and NOT compare every item to every other item, but I have tried not to spoil it for you and say what that is)

Comment: @Sam123 If an answer works for you, please also go ahead and [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple bugs in your code, not the least of which is a failure to use `enumerate` instead of `list.index`. For example, `[3, 3].index(3)` is of course always 0.

The focus of this answer is not to arrive at the most efficient solution, but to improve upon your specific approach. You can alternatively see the the [**O(n) solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627284/832230) instead.

#### Understanding list comprehensions

As a prerequisite, first understand how [multiple `for` loops can exist in a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
def sums(nums):
    return [x + y for x in nums for y in nums[:x]]
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
def sums(nums):
    output = []
    for x in nums:
       for y in nums[:x]:
           output.append(x + y)
    return output
```

### Solution using chained generator expression

```
def twosum_indices(nums, target):
    return next((i, j) for i in range(len(nums)) for j in range(len(nums[:i])) if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target))
```

Examples:

```
print(sorted(twosum_indices([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)))
[0, 1]

print(sorted(twosum_indices([3, 3], 6)))
[0, 1]
```

### Solution using generator expression with itertools

It's a tad simpler with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def twosum_indices_it(nums, target):
    return next((i, j) for (i, x), (j, y) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(nums), 2) if (x + y == target))
```

Examples:

```
print(sorted(twosum_indices_it([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)))
[0, 1]

print(sorted(twosum_indices_it([3, 3], 6)))
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def two_sum_indices(nums, target):

    def dup(i, j):
        return i == j

    d = {num: i
         for i, num in enumerate(nums)}

    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if target - num in d:
            if not dup(i, d[target - num]):
                return i, d[target - num]
    return -1, -1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(two_sum_indices([2, 7, 11, 15], target=9))
    print(two_sum_indices([3], target=6))
    print(two_sum_indices([3, 3], target=6))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def twosum_indices(nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for v in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] + nums[v] == target and i != v:
                return i, v
```

Comment: If you run this, you will find that it still has the same erroneous output.

Comment: @KennyOstrom This code works for me, what result are you getting?

Comment: nums = [3,3], target = 6, result = [0, 0], expected result [0, 1] because you rely on nums.index which will return the first occurance.

Comment: @Fibo36 It now works and that's good but the computational complexity is still higher than necessary. Basically, if you've to check `i != v`, your complexity is higher than what it needs to be. You're looping through the number pairs twice, and this may be avoidable.

Comment: @A-B-B Can you show me a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: @Fibo36 Yes, one way is to use `for v in range(len(nums[:i])):`. You then don't need the `i != v` check.