# Python: Find specific sum of values?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the sum of to values from a text file that is equal to 2020 with python. The text file contains multiple numbers each written in one line like this:

[image: text file with numbers]

What is the easiest and fastest way to do this in python?

My code reads in the file correctly but does not access the inner for loop?

```
data = []
try:
    file = open('/Users/korbinianschleifer/desktop/input.txt', 'r+')
    data = file.readlines()
    file.close()
except x:
    print('file could not be loaded')

print(len(data))

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
        if data[i]+data[j] == 2020: 
            print('solution found')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Sum on LeetCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021060/two-sum-on-leetcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data list is a list of strings, which means `+` will concatenate them ("1" + "1" is "11"), which is not the behavior you want. Parse your data to an int:

```py
# use with to avoid having to close the file manually
with open('/Users/korbinianschleifer/desktop/input.txt', 'r+') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# parse it to an int
data = [int(x) for x in data]

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(data)):
        if data[i] + data[j] == 2020:
            print("solution found", data[i], data[j])
```

As a side note, the faster way to do this is to maintain a set of values:

```py
# use with to avoid having to close the file manually
with open('/Users/korbinianschleifer/desktop/input.txt', 'r+') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# parse it to an int
data = [int(x) for x in data]

seen = set()
for v in data:
    if 2020 - v in seen:
        print("solution found", v, 2020 - v)
    seen.add(v)
```